# Constantly print Subprocess output while process is running

Tags: python, subprocess

To launch programs from my Python-scripts, I'm using the following method:

```
def execute(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    exitCode = process.returncode

    if (exitCode == 0):
        return output
    else:
        raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)
```

So when i launch a process like `Process.execute("mvn clean install")`, my program waits until the process is finished, and only then i get the complete output of my program. This is annoying if i'm running a process that takes a while to finish.

Can I let my program write the process output line by line, by polling the process output before it finishes in a loop or something?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984941/python-subprocess-popen-from-a-thread) article which might be related.

Comment: Thread instead of subprocess, i think

Comment: No, you don't need threads. The entire piping idea works because you can get read/write from processes while they are running.

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: You can also try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61188550/5664246

Comment: You can use `asynchronous` functions

Answer (score 375, accepted):

You can use [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to process lines as soon as the command outputs them: `lines = iter(fd.readline, "")`. Here's a full example showing a typical use case (thanks to @jfs for helping out):

```
from __future__ import print_function # Only Python 2.x
import subprocess

def execute(cmd):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield stdout_line 
    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)

# Example
for path in execute(["locate", "a"]):
    print(path, end="")
```

Comment: I've tried this code (with a program that takes significant time to run) and can confirm it outputs lines as they're received, rather than waiting for execution to complete. This is the superior answer imo.

Comment: Note: In Python 3, you could use `for line in popen.stdout: print(line.decode(), end='')`. To support both Python 2 and 3, use bytes literal: `b''` otherwise `lines_iterator` never ends on Python 3.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if the process pauses for a bit without writing anything to stdout there is no more input to read. You will need a loop to check whether or not the process has finished. I tried this using subprocess32 on python 2.7

Comment: @Har: wrong. The loop ends (on EOF) when the subprocess is dead. No need to check whether the process is alive or not.

Comment: Do not use `PIPE` unless you read from the pipe *while the process is running* otherwise the child process may hang (your edit that introduced `stderr=PIPE` is wrong). To read more than one pipe, you need more complex code (threads, async.IO).

Comment: it should work. To polish it, you could add `bufsize=1` (it may improve performance on Python 2), close the `popen.stdout` pipe explicitly (without waiting for the garbage collection to take care of it), and raise `subprocess.CalledProcessError` (like `check_call()`, `check_output()` do). The `print` statement is different on Python 2 and 3: you could use the softspace hack `print line,` (note: comma) to avoid doubling all newlines like your code does and passing `universal_newlines=True` on Python 3, to get text instead of bytes—[related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Comment: @tokland I think I was mistaken. It appeared as though it was ending without reading all stdout, but really there was stderr and the whole process terminated with errors which is why eof was reached

Comment: It works great, however if  it calls the python script as the child process and with time.sleep(). The iteration of line will block.

Comment: @binzhang: Can you upload somewhere that script you're running to check it?

Comment: @tokland
child_process.py:
```
import time
import sys
while True:
    print 'hello_world'
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```
In the above calling process:
```
for path in execute(["python", "child_thread.py"]):
   print(path, end="")
```

Comment: @tokland
if without sys.stdout.flush(), the iteration of line will block.
if without sys.stdout.flush() and time.sleep, the iteration will not block

Comment: @binzhang That's not an error, stdout is buffered by default on Python scripts (also for many Unix tools). Try `execute(["python", "-u", "child_thread.py"])`. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258500/python-significance-of-u-option

Comment: @binzhang: related: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279) (useful if there is no `-u`, grep's `--line-buffered` analogs in a general case)

Comment: Could you explain the second argument to print() `end=""`? That is treated as a syntax error for me when I try to run it python 3.5, and I can't figure out what  it's for.

Comment: @AnalogWeapon I'm confused. That should work on 3.5. Seed the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: You should also set `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` when you construct Popen to make sure you don't miss out on any error messages

Comment: @tvt173 Sometimes you need to capture stderr, sometimes it's ok to show it on the terminal. Anyway, not sure what would be the best way to read from two both at the same time, @J.F.Sebastian?

Comment: @tokland, really sleek code. I had to do quite a bit of reading about 'yield' and iterables after seeing your code, but I still can't really put the pieces together. Could you explain in more detail how your code works, and also what was your intuition for using yield in this case?

Comment: This does not work with the `scp` command. Trying to send a file and I'm getting no output, but it seems to work for the `tree` command.

Comment: @Klik: I think that's because `scp` autodetects if there is a terminal or not. There is info in SO, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890809/bash-stdout-redirect-of-commands-like-scp

Comment: @tokland thanks for the reference. I have a working implementation by using rsync. https://askubuntu.com/questions/44059/progress-bar-for-scp-command Doing this I was able to get a progress update of the upload

Comment: @tokland, Trying to run this with a while loop in the child process, which works great. But if I put a sleep.time(1) in, so the loop only runs once per second, I get nothing printed until the process finishes. Any thoughts?

Comment: This does not work for me when my command contains a "&" (ie - trying to run two commands together). Is there any workaround to allow the "&" sign?

Comment: How to set a timeout for it?

Comment: I'm puzzled...Does this not still suffer from the fundamental problem of potential blocking on the pipe in case the process sends a lot of data without any newlines? That is, the exact reason why the Python documentation advises to use `communicate()` instead of directly reading from the pipes?

Comment: This works! I just want to give a heads up for those that it doesn't work for... for me the problem was that the program I was executing didn't flush as I expected!

Comment: @tokland to read both streams at once, threads or async.io could be used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833897/python-read-from-subprocess-stdout-and-stderr-separately-while-preserving-order

Comment: Hi @tokland, I have a cli tool that has a progress bar (so it outputs a carriage return to always update the same line). I can't find a way to capture that progress bar. Running your script just prints an empty line. Do you know how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 147):

To print subprocess' output line-by-line as soon as its stdout buffer is flushed in Python 3:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='') # process line here

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

Notice: you do not need `p.poll()` -- the loop ends when eof is reached. And you do not need `iter(p.stdout.readline, '')` -- the read-ahead bug is fixed in Python 3.

See also, [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Comment: This solution worked for me. The accepted solution given above just went on printing blank lines for me.

Comment: I did have to add sys.stdout.flush() to get prints immediately.

Comment: @Codename: you shouldn't need `sys.stdout.flush()` in the parent -- stdout is line-buffered if it is not redirected to a file/pipe and therefore printing `line` flushes the buffer automatically. You don't need `sys.stdout.flush()` in the child too -- pass `-u` command-line option instead.

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am redirecting the output to a file.

Comment: @Codename: if it is redirected to a file then why do you need `sys.stdout.flush()`? Are you monitoring the file with `tail -f`? Have you considered `check_call(cmd, stdout=file_object)` instead?

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian - yes I wanted to have the ability to do a tail on the file. Also, I want to be able to dump the output via command line in the usual way with the > operator and not have a coded filename.

Comment: @Codename: if you want to use `>` then run `python -u your-script.py > some-file`. Notice: `-u` option that I've mentioned above (no need to use `sys.stdout.flush()`).

Comment: I have a couple of constraints. Not everyone using my script will have python command aliased to python 3 binary and I want to keep it as simple as possible for them. Does sys.stdout.flush() have any major disadvantages that I should be concerned of?

Comment: @Codename: Sprinkling your code with sys.stdout.flush() may affect performance and it is error-prone. I don't see how `-u` is related to `python` command being aliased to whatever.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the -u. But that would mean one more arg that all the users would have to add while running, right...

Comment: @Codename: no, it does not mean that. I've answered the question as stated. What to do to accommodate additional requirements depends on specifics. If you want unbuffered output in all cases; [replace `sys.stdout` with an unbuffered object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/4279) or [redirect it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279). To avoid modifying the code, you could create a shell script that set appropriate command-line parameters, environment variables for python executable. As a quick and dirty hack, you could pass `flush=True` to the `print()` function.

Comment: For my case (Python-based build scripts running under Jenkins) this happened to be the best answer at this page. But I think it is worth adding code for obtaining return code at the end - `return_code = p.wait()`

Comment: @mvidelgauz no need to call `p.wait()`—it is called on exit from the `with` block. Use `p.returncode`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian In my case `p.returncode` gave `None` - thus my comment :) (Python 3.6 on Windows and 3.4 on Ubuntu)

Comment: @mvidelgauz: It can't be `None` outside the `with`-statement unless an exception occured. Copy-paste the code as is. The indentation of the code is significant in Python

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks, I didn't realize that 'p' exists outside of `with`, i added it after `for` but inside `with`

Comment: doesn't work for me, I'm trying to capture `bully` output on Kali Linux

Comment: @vault “doesn’t work” is too generic. What did you expect to happen and what happens instead? Do you want capture stderr? Does the utility changes its output if it is redirected to a pipe? (stdout is not tty . You can check by appending “| cat” to the command  in your terminal.

Comment: @jfs here are more details based on [this code](https://pastebin.com/R9wYpYPR). `test1` and `test2` do not print anything during command execution. I waited 1 minute. `test3`, `test4`, and `test5` cause `bully` to print the usage and exit.

Comment: @vault test3-5 are broken (a list arg is wrong with shell=True and I meant you to run the "| cat" variant manually in the terminal, to see the expected output). There are not enough details to know whether test1-2 are broken too (start with passing the command as a literal list, to make sure the arg are split as you expect).  Try running your own script (that prints to stdout, stderr) as an exercise.

Comment: @jfs [These tests](https://pastebin.com/T7hqnMj0) are now all printing nothing. The `| cat` variant doesn't produce any output as you probably expected. The `sys.stdout.write` variant provided in another answer prints something in realtime (but I had problems printing bytes).

Comment: @vault: if running manually the command with `| cat` from the command line doesn't produce any output then the python code with `stdout=PIPE` shouldn't produce any output too. [`sys.stdout.write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418193/4279) answer shouldn't work at all if you use Python 3 (as my answer assumes) -- you should get TypeError. Try: `cmd = [sys.executable, '-c', "import sys, time\nfor i in range(5):\n print(i, flush=True)\n print(i*i, file=sys.stderr)\n time.sleep(1)"]`

Comment: @jfs two numbers each second, 10 lines: `0
0
1
1
4
2
9
3
16
4`

Comment: @vault [it is the expected behavior](https://repl.it/@zed1/process-command-output-while-it-is-running#main.py)

Comment: @jfs is there a way with Popen to retrieve the output line by line, with such commands?

Comment: @vault yes, just follow the links

Comment: does this code prints errors too? or should i add stderr=subprocess.PIPE ?

Comment: @kr1p to read 2 streams (stdout + stderr) at the same time but separately a different approach should be used (async.io). You can merge streams  `stderr=STDOUT`, to keep the current (simple) approach

Comment: Is anyone on windows? This isn't working for me. It just hangs until the process is complete and then it prints all at once..

Comment: How to handle KeyboardInterrupt in this case?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco If it was caused by Ctrl-C in the shell (SIGINT signal is sent to the foreground process group), then there is nothing to handle:  the child process dies by default.

Comment: @jfs this happens to other signals too? Like SIGTERM

Comment: @MichaelPacheco if you send it to the process group, then yes.

Comment: Is it possible to remove previously printed line? In progress bar each progress i printed which fills the terminal output  in each second

Answer (score 90):

Ok i managed to solve it without threads (any suggestions why using threads would be better are appreciated) by using a snippet from this question [Intercepting stdout of a subprocess while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527197/intercepting-stdout-of-a-subprocess-while-it-is-running)

```
def execute(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    # Poll process for new output until finished
    while True:
        nextline = process.stdout.readline()
        if nextline == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(nextline)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    output = process.communicate()[0]
    exitCode = process.returncode

    if (exitCode == 0):
        return output
    else:
        raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)
```

Comment: Merging the ifischer's and tokland's code works quite well (I had to change `print line,` to `sys.stdout.write(nextline); sys.stdout.flush()`. Otherwise, it would print out every two lines. Then again, this is using IPython's Notebook interface, so maybe something else was happening - regardless, explicitly calling `flush()` works.

Comment: mister you're my life saver!! really strange that this kind of things are not build-in in library itself.. cause if I write cliapp, i want to show everything what's processing in loop instantly.. s'rsly..

Comment: Can this solution be modified to constantly print *both* output and errors?  If I change `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and then call `process.stderr.readline()` from within the loop, I seem to run afoul of the very deadlock that is warned about in the documentation for the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @DavidCharles I think what you're looking for is `stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` this captures stderr, and I believe (but I've not tested) that it also captures stdin.

Comment: thanks for waiting for exit code. Didn't know how to work it out

Comment: @VitalyIsaev: there is [no need to poll the exit status in the loop, you can do it after the loop using `rc = process.wait()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: Hi all, got a small doubt, we are breaking at process.Poll() is not None, means each time it poll for the output and it will become None ?

Comment: We are using stdout = subprocess.pipe and stderr = subprocess.STDOUT like this, can anyone give me a good reference to study about these , what will happen using different combinations of these, for instance, putting stdout = subprocess.STDOUT, stderr = subprocess.pipe etc...

Comment: `execute("ls")` runs forever and plot `''` all the time. I ran this command on python3 and I needed to add str() there `nextline = str(process.stdout.readline())`. Any idea why it doesn't want to quit?

Comment: @F1sher: readline is probably returning `b""` instead of the `""` used in the code above. Try using `if nextline == b"" and...`

Comment: the problem with this is that it blocks while waiting for output, making it so you cannot do work (like look for timeout or w/e) until the program outputs another line on stdout/stderr. For a full solution you can use threading/queues a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: How does this work without creating scroll bars and identical output? It seems to just stamp and update the screen, yet if I choose which lines to yield, then it begins to scroll with the selected lines over and over again. If I let it run, then it just "updates" the existing screen. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For programs with extremely fast output this methodology was not printing all of the lines. It appears that if a program can produce significantly fast output, such that multiple lines are printed before the next call to readline then those lines will be dropped.

Answer (score 71):

There is actually a really simple way to do this when you just want to `print` the output:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def execute(command):
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Here we're simply pointing the subprocess to our own `stdout`, and using existing succeed or exception api.

Comment: This solution is simpler and cleaner than @tokland's solution, for Python 3.6. I noticed that the shell=True argument is not necessary.

Comment: Good catch, Good Will. Removed `shell=True`

Comment: Very astucious, and works perfectly with little code. Maybe you should redirect the subprocess stderr to sys.stderr too ?

Comment: Manu you certainly can. I didn't, here, because the attempt in the question was redirecting stderr to stdout.

Comment: Can you explain whats the difference between sys.stdout and subprocess.STDOUT?

Comment: Sure, @RonSerruya. [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) is a File object which allows normal writing operations. [subprocess.STDOUT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT) is a special value explicitly used to redirect stderr to the same output as stdout. Conceptually, you're saying that you want both feeds to go to the same place, rather than passing in the same value twice.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been browsing all of the stackoverflow subprocess questions and this is the only thing that worked.

Comment: Obviously the cleanest solution. It lets you forward the `stderr` as well. For `click` cli: `subprocess.check_call(command, stdout=click.get_binary_stream("stdout"), stderr=click.get_binary_stream("stderr"))`. Brilliant, thanks @AndrewRing

Comment: Why would you redirect stderr to stdout, though? That seems like a dumb thing to do. Just leave both stdout and stderr alone, and the process will inherit the standard file descriptors from Python. (That means Python has no way to capture what's being printed, but in this scenario, you are not doing that.)

Comment: @tripleee In this specific case, because that's what was asked about in the question. In a more general sense, sometimes you want a single stream of output, perhaps for unified processing, or perhaps you want to reserve stderr for your own errors, not the errors in the subprocess. It's dependent on the specifics of your use-case.

Comment: @GoodWill Look again, this code is broken on `python3.8`, you must once again use `shell=True` or else you python pukes `FileNotFoundError` and a stack trace.

Comment: Keeping `shell=True` allows you to pass the command in one go. I would suggest against doing this (see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/4521287)), and just ensure that `command` is a list of strings that make up your command. So `cp ../example.txt example.txt` should be fed as `["cp", "../example.txt", "example.txt"]`.

Comment: Never use shell=True. It needlessly invokes an extra shell process to call your program.

Comment: Can you explain why any/all of these arguments are required? As many people pointed out, some are harmful and don't seem to have any impact on the solution.

Comment: @nicbou Shell and stderr -> stdout are done to mirror the configuration in the question. Harmful is a stretch as a general statement, though there are scenarios where it can be problematic, there are also others where it is needed. As with most things, the right solution is driven by context.

Comment: I just want to get the output displayed on the screen, not saved in a file. I tried out this code snippet and it leads to the error: ` # Assuming file-like object; c2pwrite = stdout.fileno(); if stderr is None: UnsupportedOperation: fileno``. So I think it is complaining that I don't provide a file to save the output in it. Can you share how can I achieve the output to be displayed, but simply on the screen? tnx

Comment: This is a blocking call, it doesn't seem to run in the background.

Comment: @jaques-sam Correct. The question isn't asking about a background process.

Answer (score 11):

In Python >= 3.5 using `subprocess.run` works for me:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'echo foo; sleep 1; echo foo; sleep 2; echo foo'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

(getting the output during execution also works without `shell=True`)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: This is not "during execution". The `subprocess.run()` call only returns when the subprocess has finished running.

Comment: Can you explain how it is not "during execution"? Something like `>>> import subprocess; subprocess.run('top')` also seems to print "during execution" (and top never finishes). Maybe I'm not grasping some subtle difference?

Comment: If you redirect the output back to Python e.g. with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` you can only read it after `top` finishes. Your Python program is blocked during the execution of the subprocess.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. The `run` method still works if you're only interested in *seeing* the output as it's generated. If you want to do something with the output in python asynchronously you are right that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

@tokland

tried your code and corrected it for 3.4 and windows
dir.cmd is a simple dir command, saved as cmd-file

```
import subprocess
c = "dir.cmd"

def execute(command):
    popen = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)
    lines_iterator = iter(popen.stdout.readline, b"")
    while popen.poll() is None:
        for line in lines_iterator:
            nline = line.rstrip()
            print(nline.decode("latin"), end = "\r\n",flush =True) # yield line

execute(c)
```

Comment: you could [simplify your code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28319191/4279). `iter()` and `end='\r\n'` are unnecessary. Python uses universal newlines mode by default i.e., any `'\n'` is translated to `'\r\n'` during printing. `'latin'` is probably a wrong encoding, you could use `universal_newlines=True` to get text output in Python 3 (decoded using locale's preferred encoding). Don't stop on `.poll()`, there could be buffered unread data. If Python script is running in a console then its output is line-buffered; you can force line-buffering using `-u` option -- you don't need `flush=True` here.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the original question, the best way IMO is just redirecting subprocess `stdout` directly to your program's `stdout` (optionally, the same can be done for `stderr`, as in example below)

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: Not specifying anything for `stdout` and `stderr` does the same thing with less code. Though I suppose *explicit is better than implicit.*

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying the answers to this question to get the stdout from a Python script note that Python buffers its stdout, and therefore it may take a while to see the stdout.

This can be rectified by adding the following after each stdout write in the target script:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: But running Python as a subprocess of Python is crazy in the first place. Your script should simply `import` the other script; look into `multiprocessing` or `threading` if you need parallelized execution.

Comment: @triplee There are several scenarios in which running Python as a subprocess of Python is appropriate. I have a number of python batch scripts that I wish to run sequentially, daily. These can be orchestrated by a master Python script that initiates the execution, and emails me if the child script fails. Each script is sandboxed from the other - no naming conflicts. I'm not parallelising so multiprocessing and threading aren't relevant.

Comment: You could also start the other python program using a different python executable than the on that the main python program is running in e.g., `subprocess.run("/path/to/python/executable", "pythonProgramToRun.py")`

Comment: You can also use PYTHON_UNBUFFERED env var or launch python with -u to avoid this behavior

Comment: @tripleee what if the other Python script is executed on another machine?

Comment: Then you are not running Python as a direct subprocess of Python.  Having said that, there _are_ situations where it is useful or even mandatory to run Python as a subprocess of itself (for example, if the subprocess needs to catch signals independently of the parent) but I don't think this is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone wants to read from both `stdout` and `stderr` at the same time using threads, this is what I came up with:

```
import threading
import subprocess
import Queue

class AsyncLineReader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, fd, outputQueue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        assert isinstance(outputQueue, Queue.Queue)
        assert callable(fd.readline)

        self.fd = fd
        self.outputQueue = outputQueue

    def run(self):
        map(self.outputQueue.put, iter(self.fd.readline, ''))

    def eof(self):
        return not self.is_alive() and self.outputQueue.empty()

    @classmethod
    def getForFd(cls, fd, start=True):
        queue = Queue.Queue()
        reader = cls(fd, queue)

        if start:
            reader.start()

        return reader, queue


process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdoutReader, stdoutQueue) = AsyncLineReader.getForFd(process.stdout)
(stderrReader, stderrQueue) = AsyncLineReader.getForFd(process.stderr)

# Keep checking queues until there is no more output.
while not stdoutReader.eof() or not stderrReader.eof():
   # Process all available lines from the stdout Queue.
   while not stdoutQueue.empty():
       line = stdoutQueue.get()
       print 'Received stdout: ' + repr(line)

       # Do stuff with stdout line.

   # Process all available lines from the stderr Queue.
   while not stderrQueue.empty():
       line = stderrQueue.get()
       print 'Received stderr: ' + repr(line)

       # Do stuff with stderr line.

   # Sleep for a short time to avoid excessive CPU use while waiting for data.
   sleep(0.05)

print "Waiting for async readers to finish..."
stdoutReader.join()
stderrReader.join()

# Close subprocess' file descriptors.
process.stdout.close()
process.stderr.close()

print "Waiting for process to exit..."
returnCode = process.wait()

if returnCode != 0:
   raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returnCode, command)
```

I just wanted to share this, as I ended up on this question trying to do something similar, but none of the answers solved my problem. Hopefully it helps someone!

Note that in my use case, an external process kills the process that we `Popen()`.

Comment: I've had to use something almost exactly like this for python2.   While something like this should have been provided in python2, it is not so something like this is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @jfs's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319191), here is a complete working example for you to play with. Requires Python 3.7 or newer.

**sub.py**

```py
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```py
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
import sys

with Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'sub.py'], bufsize=1, stdout=PIPE, text=True
           ) as sub:
    for line in sub.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

`-u` is to avoid buffering the outputs - alternatively, `print(i, flush=True)` also works.

Comment: Flush did it for my prints during a while loop.

Comment: Simplest approach that worked for me -- edited to remove `flush=True` requirement - several comments say it, none put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here addressed all of my needs.

1. No threads for stdout (no Queues, etc, either)
2. Non-blocking as I need to check for other things going on
3. Use PIPE as I needed to do multiple things, e.g. stream output, write to a log file and return a string copy of the output.

A little background: I am using a ThreadPoolExecutor to manage a pool of threads, each launching a subprocess and running them concurrency. (In Python2.7, but this should work in newer 3.x as well). I don't want to use threads just for output gathering as I want as many available as possible for other things (a pool of 20 processes would be using 40 threads just to run; 1 for the process thread and 1 for stdout...and more if you want stderr I guess)

I'm stripping back a lot of exception and such here so this is *based* on code that works in production. Hopefully I didn't ruin it in the copy and paste. Also, feedback very much welcome!

```
import time
import fcntl
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Make stdout non-blocking when using read/readline
proc_stdout = proc.stdout
fl = fcntl.fcntl(proc_stdout, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(proc_stdout, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

def handle_stdout(proc_stream, my_buffer, echo_streams=True, log_file=None):
    """A little inline function to handle the stdout business. """
    # fcntl makes readline non-blocking so it raises an IOError when empty
    try:
        for s in iter(proc_stream.readline, ''):   # replace '' with b'' for Python 3
            my_buffer.append(s)

            if echo_streams:
                sys.stdout.write(s)

            if log_file:
                log_file.write(s)
    except IOError:
        pass

# The main loop while subprocess is running
stdout_parts = []
while proc.poll() is None:
    handle_stdout(proc_stdout, stdout_parts)

    # ...Check for other things here...
    # For example, check a multiprocessor.Value('b') to proc.kill()

    time.sleep(0.01)

# Not sure if this is needed, but run it again just to be sure we got it all?
handle_stdout(proc_stdout, stdout_parts)

stdout_str = "".join(stdout_parts)  # Just to demo
```

I'm sure there is overhead being added here but it is not a concern in my case. Functionally it does what I need. The only thing I haven't solved is why this works perfectly for log messages but I see some `print` messages show up later and all at once.

Answer (score 1):

This PoC constantly reads the output from a process and can be accessed when needed. Only the last result is kept, all other output is discarded, hence prevents the PIPE from growing out of memory:

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading
import Queue


class FlushPipe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.command = ['python', './print_date.py']
        self.process = None
        self.process_output = Queue.LifoQueue(0)
        self.capture_output = threading.Thread(target=self.output_reader)

    def output_reader(self):
        for line in iter(self.process.stdout.readline, b''):
            self.process_output.put_nowait(line)

    def start_process(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.command,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.capture_output.start()

    def get_output_for_processing(self):
        line = self.process_output.get()
        print ">>>" + line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flush_pipe = FlushPipe()
    flush_pipe.start_process()

    now = time.time()
    while time.time() - now < 10:
        flush_pipe.get_output_for_processing()
        time.sleep(2.5)

    flush_pipe.capture_output.join(timeout=0.001)
    flush_pipe.process.kill()
```

print_date.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print str(time.time())
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

output: You can clearly see that there is only output from ~2.5s interval nothing in between.

```
>>>1520535158.51
>>>1520535161.01
>>>1520535163.51
>>>1520535166.01
```

Answer (score 1):

This works at least in Python3.4

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in process.stdout:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

Comment: This has the problem that it blocks in the loop until the process has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-u` Python option with `subprocess.Popen()` if you want to print from stdout while the process is running. (`shell=True` is necessary, despite the risks...)

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
import queue

cmd='esptool.py --chip esp8266 write_flash -z 0x1000 /home/pi/zero2/fw/base/boot_40m.bin'
cmd2='esptool.py --chip esp32 -b 115200 write_flash -z 0x1000 /home/pi/zero2/fw/test.bin'
cmd3='esptool.py --chip esp32 -b 115200 erase_flash'

class ExecutorFlushSTDOUT(object):
    def __init__(self,timeout=15):
        self.process = None
        self.process_output = queue.Queue(0)
        self.capture_output = threading.Thread(target=self.output_reader)
        self.timeout=timeout
        self.result=False
        self.validator=None
        
    def output_reader(self):
        start=time.time()
        while self.process.poll() is None and (time.time() - start) < self.timeout:
            try:
                if not self.process_output.full():
                    line=self.process.stdout.readline()
                    if line:
                        line=line.decode().rstrip("\n")
                        start=time.time()
                        self.process_output.put(line)
                        if self.validator:
                            if self.validator in line: print("Valid");self.result=True

            except:pass
        self.process.kill()
        return
            
    def start_process(self,cmd_list,callback=None,validator=None,timeout=None):
        if timeout: self.timeout=timeout
        self.validator=validator
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        self.capture_output.start()
        line=None
        self.result=False
        while self.process.poll() is None:
            try:
                if not self.process_output.empty():
                    line = self.process_output.get()
                if line:
                    if callback:callback(line)
                    #print(line)
                    line=None
            except:pass                
        error = self.process.returncode
        if error:
            print("Error Found",str(error))
            raise RuntimeError(error)
        return self.result

execute = ExecutorFlushSTDOUT()

def liveOUTPUT(line):
    print("liveOUTPUT",line)
    try:
        if "Writing" in line:
            line=''.join([n for n in line.split(' ')[3] if n.isdigit()])
            print("percent={}".format(line))
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    


result=execute.start_process(cmd2,callback=liveOUTPUT,validator="Hash of data verified.")

print("Finish",result)
```

Answer (score -2):

> Simple better than complex.

`os` library has built-in module `system`. You should execute your code and see the output.

```py
import os
os.system("python --version")
# Output
"""
Python 3.8.6
0
"""
```

After version it is also printed return value as `0`.

Comment: In this example you cannot process output?

Comment: You should check from documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

Comment: @EinoMäkitalo question asking to see constantly printing. If your script file is different from actual execute file, it works. If you run code you will see console output as well. Doc says: `Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of
the executed command. If command generates any output, it will be sent to
the interpreter standard output stream.`

Answer (score -4):

In Python 3.6 I used this:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "command"
output = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
print(process)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this particular question. Waiting for the subprocess to finish before obtaining its output is specifically and precisely what the OP is trying to avoid. The old legacy function `subprocess.call()` has some warts which are fixed by newer functions; in Python 3.6 you would generally use `subprocess.run()` for this; for convenience, the older wrapper function `subprocess.check_output()` is also still available - it returns the actual output from the process (this code would return the exit code only, but even then print something undefined instead).