# How to test a directory of files for gzip and uncompress gzipped files in Python using zcat?

Tags: python, logging, gzip, compression, zcat

I'm in my 2nd week of Python and I'm stuck on a directory of zipped/unzipped logfiles, which I need to parse and process.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
import os
import sys
import operator
import zipfile
import zlib
import gzip
import subprocess

if sys.version.startswith("3."):
    import io
    io_method = io.BytesIO
else:
    import cStringIO
    io_method = cStringIO.StringIO

for f in glob.glob('logs/*'):
    file = open(f,'rb')        
    new_file_name = f + "_unzipped"
    last_pos = file.tell()

    # test for gzip
    if (file.read(2) == b'\x1f\x8b'):
        file.seek(last_pos)

    #unzip to new file
    out = open( new_file_name, "wb" )
    process = subprocess.Popen(["zcat", f], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
      if process.poll() != None:
        break;

    output = io_method(process.communicate()[0])
    exitCode = process.returncode


    if (exitCode == 0):
      print "done"
      out.write( output )
      out.close()
    else:
      raise ProcessException(command, exitCode, output)
```

which I've "stitched" together using these SO answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)) and blogposts ([here](http://codebright.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/139/))

However, it does not seem to work, because my test file is 2.5GB and the script has been chewing on it for 10+mins plus I'm not really sure if what I'm doing is correct anyway.

**Question:**
If I don't want to use GZIP module and need to de-compress chunk-by-chunk (actual files are >10GB), how do I uncompress and save to file using zcat and subprocess in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: I am unclear on what your goal is. Are you trying to uncompress all of the files in a directory? Equivalent to: `gunzip *.gz` ? Do you any specific objection to using the gzip module?

Comment: The directory contains zipped and unzipped files. I need to process both in a single process, so my idea was to (1) first run over the directory, (2) pick zipped files and unzip to new file (3) then do a 2nd run to process. Not sure if this is the best way to go though

Comment: re: objection `gzip`, isn't it, that gzip is very slow - like mentioned [here](http://codebright.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/139/)?

Comment: Do you need to seek on the logfiles, or is reading them in one pass sufficient?

Comment: I need to retrieve the first log entry (line) per file (zipped/unzipped), extract the date and store it with filepath. Next pass will be processing log files line-by-line in sorted order.

Comment: You probably need a buffer size for your `Popen` call.

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `_unzipped`,  `.poll` or `io_method`. Perhaps there is something subtle that I've missed. I posted the obvious answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should read the first line of every file in the logs subdirectory, unzipping as required:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import gzip
import subprocess

for f in glob.glob('logs/*'):
  if f.endswith('.gz'):
    # Open a compressed file. Here is the easy way:
    #   file = gzip.open(f, 'rb')
    # Or, here is the hard way:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['zcat', f], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    file = proc.stdout
  else:
    # Otherwise, it must be a regular file
    file = open(f, 'rb')

  # Process file, for example:
  print f, file.readline()
```