# get the output of an (OS) command that hasn't returned yet in Python

Tags: python

To get an output of a command we could do this

```
os.popen("ls").read()
```

But suppose I have a command that I don't want to wait for it to return. In fact, I want to keep it running, and occasionally spit out some output. 
(Eg., `java PrintEvery5`) (Suppose the `PrintEvery5` would print a line every 5 seconds).

How do *subscribe* to the process/thread and grab the output of this?

I've tried the following, which didn't seem to work.

```
### file: deqthread.py
import threading, os, subprocess

class DeqThread(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self):
         super(DeqThread, self).__init__()
         self.f=os.popen("java PrintEvery5")

     def run(self):
         print("in run")

     def readResult(self):
         return self.f.read() 


thread1 = DeqThread()
thread1.start()                                                                                                         

while True:

    print(thread1.readResult())
```

Running `python deqthread.py`, I don't see any output. THe whole thing just hangs there.

When I try this, I could see the output. (ie., it keeps printing to the console),

```
$python <ENTER>
>>> import os
>>> os.system("java PrintEvery5")
```

So what do I need to change in my `deqthread.py` file so that I can get output out of my command?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the the `check_output` method in `subprocess` module? It allows you to run a command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello Java!"])
print output
```

So `__init__` could become:

```
def __init__(self):
     super(DeqThread, self).__init__()
```

And `readResult` could become:

```
def readResult(self):
     def readResult(self):
         output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello Java!"])
         return output
```

See documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: No, I didn't even know what to look for. Thanks for the suggestion! (This is where one gets to say "you don't know what you don't know!" :) )

Comment: That still blocks until the call returns.

Comment: try removing `self.f=os.popen("java PrintEvery5")` from `__int__` and place `output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello Java!"]) return output` in `readResult`. I just ran it on my machine and its working. See the edit.

Comment: It works because `echo` returns in nanoseconds.  The issue the OP is trying to solve is to capture stdout from a long-running process before it finishes.

Comment: here's another thread about intercepting stdout from a subprocess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running maybe that'll help

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess.Popen(), then redirect stdout to subprocess.PIPE. Finally, get the output from the stdout member of sub-process instance. The example shows as below:

foo.py:

```
import time

count = 5
while count > 0:
    print 'Hello'
    count -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

main.py:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', 'foo.py'],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print("OUTPUT: " + line.rstrip())
```

Comment: No, this still blocks until `foo.py` returns.

Comment: You can create a thread to catch the output, here is just an example.