# printing the output of shell command from python subprocess

Tags: swing, subprocess, jython

I am running a shell script which emits lots of line while executing...they are just status output rather than the actual output....

I want them to be displayed on a JTextArea. I am working on jython. The piece of my code looks like:

```
self.console=JTextArea(20,80)
cmd = "/Users/name/galaxy-dist/run.sh"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
self.console.append(p.stdout.read())
```

This will wait until the command finishes and prints the output. But I want to show the realtime out put to mimic the console. Anybody have the idea ?

Comment: I think your answer is over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running

Answer (score 1):

You're making things more complicated than they need to be. The [Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) state the following about the stream arguments:

> With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; **the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.** [my emphasis]

Therefore, if you want the subprocess' output to go to your stdout, simply leave those arguments blank:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

In fact, you aren't using any of the more advanced features of the `Popen` constructor, and this particular example doesn't need any parsing by the shell, so you can simplify it further with the `subprocess.call()` function:

```
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

If you still want the return code, simply set a variable equal to this call:

```
return_code = subprocess.call(cmd)
```