# windows python stdout and stderr to two different files

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I would like to output the stdout and stderr  to two different log files. 
i have tried this code but it only outputs the error to error log , but output is not  redirected to  runtime.log  file.

the code is being run on windows and mostly robocopy is done in the code.

```
saveerr = sys.stderr 
fsock = open('error.log', 'a') 
sys.stderr = fsock

saveout = sys.stdout
fsock1 = open('runtime.log', 'a') 
sys.stdout = fsock1
```

the sys.stdout   area is not working. please let me know any correction in this code.

here is my entire code

```
import sys

saveerr = sys.stderr 
fsock = open('error.log', 'a') 
sys.stderr = fsock

saveout = sys.stdout
fsock1 = open('runtime.log', 'a') 
sys.stdout = fsock1

##For site  AUCB-NET-01   from source folder AUDC-RSTOR-01  E:\Canberra
exit_code1 = subprocess.call('robocopy \\\\aucb-net-01\\d$ \\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aucb-net-01  /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1', shell=True)
print ("exitcoode1=", exit_code1)
```

thanks to everyone for reading my post.

Comment: How are you launching Robocopy? (And why is this tagged 'PowerShell' ?)

Comment: This should divert *your* stdout to runtime.log. If you're launching robocopy though you'll want to divert its stdout to the file. Post the code you're using to launch robocopy

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment your code should divert **your** stdout to the file. To get robocopy's stdout to go there too just echo each line to your stdout as shown in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319191/6550457

---

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

saveerr = sys.stderr 
fsock = open('error.log', 'a') 
sys.stderr = fsock

saveout = sys.stdout
fsock1 = open('runtime.log', 'a') 
sys.stdout = fsock1

cmd = 'robocopy \\\\aucb-net-01\\d$ \\\\nasaudc01\\remote_site_sync\\aucb-net-01  /E /MIR /W:2 /R:1'
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=sys.stdout, stderror=sys.stderr, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
exit_code1 = p.wait()
```

see @eryksuns comments about robo copy and it's exit codes. http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Comment: i would like to do six robocopy  in same  this script  , how can i do so ..... will the above script work for all six robocopy commands......

Comment: yes, it'll work. You can either duplicate the last 4 lines 6 times over or create an array of cmd values and iterate over them

Comment: No problem, if this has resolved your issue could you please tick the answer as accepted.

Comment: It would be simpler to pass `Popen` the arguments `stdout=sys.stdout` and `stderr=sys.stderr`, and then check `p.wait()` for [robocopy's exit code](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html). The intermediating pipe and decoding of text aren't really necessary.

Comment: A lot of programs use a generic 0 for success and any other value is an error code, but robocopy uses information codes. So, for example, `subprocess.check_call` thinks robocopy has failed when it actually succeeded. I think that's worth noting, so can you include the link for the exit codes?