# Python subprocess process piped output programmatically

Tags: python, subprocess

I would to run a command using `popen`, but I want to pipe the output to another method. My goal is to display a custom output: pipe the build output from compiling my project to a method which just outputs the progress percentage, and I also want to log the raw output to a file.

I don't want to have to wait for the subprocess to finish to be able to read its STDOUT.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use the subprocess.PIPE and pass your subprocess's stdout pipe directly to something else...

Comment: I want the "something else" to be a method in my python program. I didn't want to create more scripts, and I want the process to remain all in my one python command. This is what I'm trying currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running/4417735#4417735

Comment: Not very clear what you mean - can you post some example code?