# communicating with CMD while saving response live

Tags: python, file, cmd

Is there any possible way to communicate with the `cmd` and at the **same time** save all its output to a file?

I mean that after every command the output will be saved, not at the end of the sub-process.

I want it to be something like this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    with open("log.txt", "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(process.stdout.readlines())
        process.stdin(raw_input())
```

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this, either by creating an iterator from the read or readline functions and do:

```
     import subprocess
     import sys
     with open('test.log', 'w') as f:
         process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         for c in iter(lambda: process.stdout.read(1), ''):
             sys.stdout.write(c)
             f.write(c)
```

or

```
     import subprocess
     import sys
     with open('test.log', 'w') as f:
         process = subprocess.Popen(your_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
             sys.stdout.write(line)
             f.write(line)
```

Comment: If i need that the commands will be read from a file and not from the user?