# Python script gives no output

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I have the following python script which is trying to get file count in every sub-directory under the given path , but it gives no output :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

import subprocess
import os

command=r'ssh <some-server> "(echo \"import os\" ; echo \"for r,d,f in os.walk(\"/home/vibhora/\"): print (r,len(f))\")| python"'
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", "{0}".format("command")], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = ssh.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```

Anybody has any idea what Am I doing wrong here ? Any better approach to get the file list are most welcome , Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running

Comment: Nope , Still doesn't seem to work .

Comment: have you tried debugging it? Try running 'ssh <some-server>.......' from the commandline and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `"command"` instead of `command`.

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", "{0}".format(`command`)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`)
```