# Excute a program multiple times sequently in same console

Tags: python, process

I want to excute a program multiple times in a loop with diffrenet argument eveytime, but avoid opening new coonsole window everytime.
I tried `os.system()`, `Popen` but no success.

example for what I tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for i in range(10):
    process = Popen("myProgram.exe i", shell=False,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
```

also tried using `&` `;` `pause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this case you should set the parameter `shell=True`. Here's an example:

Say you want to run `foo` 10 times from `bar`:

**foo.py**

```
import sys

with open("result.txt", "a") as f:
    print("debug")
    f.write(sys.argv[1])
```

**bar.py**

```
import subprocess

for i in range(10):
    CMD = "python foo.py %s" % i
    p = subprocess.Popen(CMD, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE))
    print(p.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

After running `python bar.py`, we have the file:

**result.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

**stdout**

```
debug

debug

debug

...

debug
```

Comment: but shell=true won't show me console at all, right?
I prefer to see it to know how the progress going

Comment: With `shell=True`, "the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`". Also, I've updated my answer with this requirement. This will print a dump of the output of each iteration once it is completed. For a live view of the output of the scripts, see the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running).