# Subprocess STDOUT is not Live

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

After looking through pretty much all relevant articles and trying everything, I can't make this work, so many thanks in advance for taking a look.

I wrote the following code to activate second script from the first script:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', path_calculator + 
'calculator.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
    line = str(line)
    line = line[2:]
    line = line[:-3]
```

The point of this code is to get the live output of the 'calculator' in the first script, because other scripts are depending on that output.
The code does provide the correct output, but only when the 'calculator' finishes. It then outputs all data in one go. That's not sufficient. I need the output the moment it comes out of the 'calculator'.

Funny thing is that it actually works on my mac, but I can't get it to work on Windows. 
** A few hours later now, I found out that it's not my Mac that it works on, but it's Pycharm (which I use on my mac) that it works on. If I run it in the terminal on my mac it doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Because u said it worked on mac but not Windows, I think you should change `path_calculator + 'calculator.py'` into `os.path.join(path_calculator, 'calculator.py')`

Comment: Thanks for replying. After a day of programming, I was not so clear in explaining the problem. I edited the explanation. Hope that clears up!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constantly print Subprocess output while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)