# Flask: Display Flash Messages Constantly

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I developed a flask app which runs a mathematical optimization script (`PuLP`+ Python) for user provided data input. Since the computation takes quite a while, I want to display the optimizer's print statements constantly (without refreshing) on my webpage.

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running) I managed to run a `subprocess`with my `.py` script. Within this script, the `print()` statement does what it should, however I can only see the output in the command line. By using `flash()` I managed to display the output, yet it gets rendered only once the computation has finished and the page is reloaded. I try to output the `print()` statements in realtime within my HTML. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Excerpt from `routes.py`:

```python
@app.route('/optimize', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def solve():
    path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'optimization', 'assets')
    file = "test.py"
    execute(file, path)

return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

The `execute(file,path)` function:

```python
import os
import subprocess as sub

def execute(command, directory):

    # change directory to execute the command
    os.chdir(directory)

    proc = sub.Popen(['python','-u', command], stdout=sub.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) # Python 2: bufsize=1

    for stdout_line in proc.stdout:
        print(stdout_line.rstrip() + '\n')
        flash(stdout_line.rstrip(), 'python_print')
    proc.stdout.close()
    return_code = proc.wait()
    if return_code:
        raise sub.CalledProcessError(return_code, command)
```

And finally my `HTML` which is rendered in the `home` route:

```html
{% with prints = get_flashed_messages(category_filter=["python_print"]) %}
{% if prints %}
<div class="content-section">
    <h3>Solver Status</h3>
    <ul>
        {%- for message in prints %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions provided I changed my approach and got it running. Instead of using `subprocess`, the solver is imported as module. I'm generating a `.txt` using the python `logging` module rather than trying to catch the `print` statements. This file is streamed constantly using `flask response` + `yield` and parsed via `AJAX`. The getter is called in jQuery via `setInterval` (here: `1Hz`) and added to my HTML. I will post some snippets below for anyone dealing with the same issue.

Thanks for your support!

**Flask optimize route:**

```python
import supplierAllocation.optimization.optimizer as optimizer

@app.route('/optimize')
def optimize():

    if session.get('input_file') is not None:

        # Get input_file
        input_file = session.get('input_file')

        # Path to logfile
        log_file = os.path.join(
            app.config['LOG_FOLDER'], session.get('log_file'))

        # Assign random unique hex file name from session to output file
        out_file_fn = session.get('session_ID') + '.xlsx'
        output_file = os.path.join(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], out_file_fn)

        # Search for outdated output; if present: delete
        if session.get('output_file') is None:
            session['output_file'] = out_file_fn
        else:
            session_output = os.path.join(
                app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], session.get('output_file'))
            silent_remove(session_output)

        # Pass input and output parameter to solver
        optimizer.launch_solver(input_file, output_file, log_file)

    else:
        flash("Please upload your data before launching the solver!", 'warning')

    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**Flask streaming route:**

```python
@app.route('/streamLog')
def stream_logfile():
    if session.get('log_file') is None:
        return Response(status=204)
    else:
        session_log = os.path.join(
            app.config['LOG_FOLDER'], session.get('log_file'))

        def stream():
            with open(session_log, "rb") as file:
                yield file.read()

        return Response(stream(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

**Call of AJAX request on button click:**

```js
// Print solver output with 1Hz
var session_log = setInterval(get_Log, 1000);
```

**AJAX request in jQuery:**

```js
// AJAX Request to download solutions
function get_Log() {
  console.log('Sending AJAX request...');
  $.ajax({
    url: "streamLog",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(result) {
      $("#code-wrapper").html(result);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("ERROR! Logfile could not be retrieved.");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is how message flashing is supposed to work, i.e. it will display all the messages for a particular end point all at once.

I am not sure about the exact implementation since I have not looked at the source code for `flash()` and `get_flash_messages()` but this is my understanding of what might be happening in the background, every message you flash with `flash` function in your python code it gets appended to an iterable, and when you call the `get_flashed_messages()` it returns that iterable back, which you can loop over to get the messages.

Though your `execute()` function is adding messages to that iterable before the process has been completed, but notice the `execute` function is being called inside the view `solve` and the actual `redirect` can happen only after the `execute` function has completed its execution, and that's when the template `home` will gets the iterable having all the flashed messages.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi, your answer makes perfectly sense! Can you think of an alternative implementation to get the print statements in realtime?

Comment: I am not sure if this is even possible because you see the the page will display message only when it is loaded or reloaded, I don't think there is any way to display the messages without reloading the page. One ugly idea is to `redirect` or `render_template` for every message you flash, though it is not really a good idea for a production website. Please consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: I upvoted (@rohit), but it is not displayed due to my lack of reputation ;-) I thought of rendering (`redirect`) after every `flash`, however I want all the output to appear in a container which is scrollable, so one can trace back the activities of the solver. Is there any other way to display `print()` statements?

Comment: I don't think so, the best you can do is to return the output of solver all at once and then pass that to your template.

Comment: I suggest you look at **Flask Socketio**. It is a flask module that allows bidirectional communication between a server and a client (real time in a way). [https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @Tobin: I also stumpled upon the `Socketio` module, but struggled a bit with getting the desired results. However, I got it up and running :) Thanks for your comment!