# Python: simultaneous use of os.fork(), os.pipe() and subprocess.Popen issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, fork

Basically, I have the following code segment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import shlex
import paho.mqtt.client as paho

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r, w = os.pipe()
    processId = os.fork()
    if processId:
        # wait to ensure tshark is started appropriately
        os.close(w)
        r = os.fdopen(r,'r')
        while True:
             str = r.read()
             print("{} {}".format("Message from child: ",str))
             if str == "ok":
                 break
        print("Parent exit")
    else:
        os.close(r)
        w = os.fdopen(w,'w')
        cmd = "tshark | grep EAP"
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        w.write("ok")
        # send signal to parent stating tshark has started appropriately
        for output in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
            pass #if contains EAP packet, do something
```

I am trying to create a child process that capture packets through `tshark`, instantly based on the packet captured to perform some action. I attempted to fork a process so that for the parent process, some action can be done and the child process can capture the packets. I also would like to first ensure child has successfully started `tshark` before the parent process continue the job.

## Here comes my questions...

1) Is the `subprocess.Popen`'s pipe interfering with the pipe created from `os.pipe()`?
I was thinking that both were not interfering with each other since they are two distincting sets of pipe. However, I noticed that the parent process cannot receive the message through the read pipe and only if `subprocess` has some output, the parent will then receive the message.  I I need some help here...

2) Is there any approach that the output from `subprocess` can be capture on a line basis? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running) suggested that it is possible to capture output while `subprocess` is still running, however it only returns the output once the buffer size is reached.

3) Is it a good or bad approach for mixing `os.pipe()` , `os.fork()` and `subprocess.Popen` all at once? I am just not sure whether someone will be doing this or there is any better alternatives? Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `str = r.read()` is going to read until the pipe closes. Pipes are streaming, not datagrams. Perhaps use `.readline()` and `w.write("ok\n")`, so that it knows when to stop reading data and return?

Comment: Erm... That does not work... I understand that pipes are streaming but I am wondering whether the `r` file descriptor is reading`subprocess`' pipe rather than the one created through `os.pipe()`

thanks for helping anyway :)