# missing stdout before subprocess.Popen crash

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, output-buffering

I'm using python to run some test cases for a C++ app I'm working on. When I run it in a terminal I see regular output right up until an **`assert()`**. With the following python code wrapping the call I miss a pile of stdout before the assert (yes, flush is not called, but why the difference between python and bash).

```
import subprocess as sp
cmd = ["myapp"]
proc = sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE)

# runs in a thread while the main thread calls proc.wait(timeout)
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(line.decode('ascii'))
```

The only fix I've found is to add `cmd = ['stdbuf', '-o0'] + cmd` ([catching stdout...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40453613/1888983)). **Is there a python way to do whatever magic `stdbuf` does?**

- I'm already using readline - [catching stdout...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1606870/1888983), [read subprocess...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2813530/1888983)
- Using `bufsize=0` or `1` doesn't help - [catching stdout...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156679/1888983)
- I found it interesting that you can re-open a FD without buffering,
  `unbuffered = os.fdopen(proc.stdout.fileno(), 'rb', 0)`, but this didn't help either - [unbuffered stdout in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882060/1888983)
- Much of the other buffering solutions I found were for python's output, e.g. [disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering), not reading stdout from the subprocess.

I noted that `os.fdopen(proc.stdout.fileno(), 'r', 0)` (without the `b`) produced `ValueError: can't have unbuffered text I/O`, which makes me wonder if using `universal_newlines=True`/`text=True` implicitly enables buffering and maybe even `readline()` is forced into it, but I'd have hoped that would happen within python and not in the pipe that gets destroyed when the subprocess crashes.

Comment: When writing to a pipe, output is buffered by default. If the program crashes, the last buffer won't be flushed.

Comment: You can do what `stdbuf` does by using the [`pty`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) module.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. Is it possible not to use a pipe? e.g. reading directly to a `StringIO`. What did you have in mind for `pty`? based on the [linked dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147141/force-a-3rd-party-program-to-flush-its-output-when-called-through-subprocess), is it that `assert()` flushes only if stdout is a tty and I should use `pty.openpty()` with `Popen()`?

Comment: The problems isn't the reading, it's the writing in the subprocess. You can't make it write directly into a string, it's writing to its stdout stream. The pty is the way you do it without a pipe.

Comment: I see, so `Popen` necessarily creates a pipe. I guess it's in the name :P, but `stdout=sp.PIPE` implies it's configurable. Thanks!

Comment: It defaults to a pipe, but you can override that. So you can create the pty and use that instead, as shown in the dup.