# Getting output from subprocess.run() in python on the fly

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run a number of shell commands inside python, and I'd like to have them being outputted on the fly (similar to the way they would come in bash).

To do so I'm using:

```
import subprocess
cmd='''
x=1
while [ $x -le 5 ]; do
  echo "$x"
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 2
done
'''
out=subprocess.run(cmd,
    check=True, shell=True,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out.stdout
```

Questions:

1. However, I only get the full output when the script ends. Is there a way to get it as it goes?
2. In case it is relevant, I actually don't need to get anything from my run (i.e. not going to pipe it or anything.). Should I instead be using `os.system`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Popen`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd = '''
x=1
while [ $x -le 5 ]; do
  echo "$x"
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
  sleep 2
done
'''
out = Popen(
    cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
print(out)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the output being printed as it comes out (i.e. with the 2 seconds wait time). Is it because I'm on jupyter/ipython?

Comment: Hmm. Really I don't know, but I got the results. It printed out the numbers.

Comment: I've tested it again in terminal, and it returns the same. My main point was getting the output *on the fly*, rather than all at the end of the evaluation. Meaning, I would see the numbers being printed with the 2 seconds interval

Comment: It is waiting 10 seconds. I guess it's because you wrote 5 to the cmd. 5 * 2 = 10 seconds.

Comment: Exactly. But my question was how to get the output as it is being printed, rather than having `Popen`, or `subprocess` waiting for the full evaluation run. I see now that [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running) had the same question

Comment: I understood what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subpocess.check_output()`:

```
co = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
print(co.decode('utf-8'))
```