# Can I log a subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I have to lanch some `apt install` commands inside a Python script, and this is possible using the subprocess. But the problem is that I can't see the installation progress (error, completed, didn't start, ongoing etc.). Is there a way to print the `apt` logs just like in bash?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constantly print Subprocess output while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)

Comment: Can you provide some code indicating how you are using Python for it? According to the [subprocess library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), if you use subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True) maybe you get what you want.

Comment: not really.. what i need is something that prints every line just like in cmd. capture_output looks like something i dont need.. but thank you anyway for the effort. omw to check @RonSerruya

Comment: sadly, @RonSerruya answer doesn't solve the problem. Still, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example. It uses iter() over `stdout` from Popen. Since you didn't povide a code how do you call apt get I used ping for demo but the principle is the same.

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "3", "google.com"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line)
process.stdout.close()
return_code = process.wait()
```

Comment: working! now the problem is giving sudo privileges to the command, but that's another story. thank you so much!

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache Just use ` echo password | sudo -S Command`

Comment: sadly it doesn't work, and i don't know why. it just gets stuck.. for now, a workaround is to launch the script through a .sh and asking the password before. but don't worry, i'll figure it out!