# Unable to print TCPcump information using python subprocess

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking, scripting, subprocess

I wanted to process tcpdump output in a python script and so far I was able to get to this implementation

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError
import os
import signal
import time

if __name__=="__main__":
    
    cmd = ["sudo","tcpdump", "-c","1000","-i","any","port","22","-n"]
    with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        try:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line,flush=True) # process line here   
    
        except KeyboardInterrupt:       
            print("Quitting")
```

This is what I uderstood from the second answer of [this previously asked question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)
While it is not waiting for the subprocess to complete to print the output of the tcpdump, I still get the output in chunks of 20-30 lines at a time. Is there a way to read even if there is a single line in stdout pf the subprocess?

PS: I am running this script on a raspberry Pi 4 with ubuntu server 22.04.1

Comment: Tangentially, the code you put inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` should be absolutely trivial. The condition is only useful when you `import` this code; if all the useful functionality is excluded when you `import`, you will never want to do that anyway. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpdump` uses a larger buffer if you connect its standard output to a pipe. You can easily see this by running the following two commands. (I changed the count from 1000 to 40 and removed `port 22` in order to quickly get output on my system.)

```
$ sudo tcpdump -c 40 -i any -n
$ sudo tcpdump -c 40 -i any -n | cat
```

The first command prints one line at a time. The second collects everything in a buffer and prints everything when `tcpdump` exits. The solution is to tell `tcpdump` to use line buffering with the `-l` argument.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -l -c 40 -i any -n | cat
```

Do the same in your Python program.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["sudo", "tcpdump", "-l", "-c", "40", "-i", "any", "-n"]
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, text=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line.strip())
```

When I run this, I get one line printed at a time.

Note that `universal_newlines` is a backward-compatible alias for `text`, so the latter should be preferred.